# Proxy using Twython

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, twython

I keep getting this error everytime I try running my code through proxy. I have gone through every single link available on how to get my code running behind proxy and am simply unable to get this done.

```
import twython
import requests
TWITTER_APP_KEY = 'key' #supply the appropriate value
TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET = 'key-secret' 
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'token'
TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'secret'


t = twython.Twython(app_key=TWITTER_APP_KEY, 
app_secret=TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET, 
oauth_token=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, 
oauth_token_secret=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
client_args = {'proxies': {'http': 'proxy.company.com:10080'}})
```

now if I do

```
t = twython.Twython(app_key=TWITTER_APP_KEY, 
        app_secret=TWITTER_APP_KEY_SECRET, 
        oauth_token=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, 
        oauth_token_secret=TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        client_args = client_args)

print t.client_args
```

I get only a {}

and when I try running

```
t.update_status(status='See how easy this was?')
```

I get this problem :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
t.update_status(status='See how easy this was?')
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twython\endpoints.py", line 86, in update_status
return self.post('statuses/update', params=params)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twython\api.py", line 223, in post
return self.request(endpoint, 'POST', params=params, version=version)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twython\api.py", line 213, in request
content = self._request(url, method=method, params=params, api_call=url)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twython\api.py", line 134, in _request
response = func(url, **requests_args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py",    line 377, in post
return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 335, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 438, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 327, in send
raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries  exceeded with url: /1.1/statuses/update.json (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)
```

I have searched everywhere. Tried everything that I possibly could. The only resources available were :

https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/advanced_usage.html#manipulate-the-request-headers-proxies-etc

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twython-talk/GLjjVRHqHng

https://github.com/fumieval/twython/commit/7caa68814631203cb63231918e42e54eee4d2273

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twython-talk/mXVL7XU4jWw

There were no topics I could find here (on Stack Overflow) either.

Please help. Hope someone replies. If you have already done this please help me with some code example.

Comment: From your writeup it looks like you printed `t.client_arg` when you meant to print `t.client_args`. Are you sure you printed the right thing there?

Comment: I have corrected it. I was printing `t.client_args`. Thank you for pointing that out. The problem remains though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't using your proxy. The example shows, you specified a proxy for plain `HTTP` but your stackstrace shows a `HTTPSConnectionPool`. Your local machine probably can't resolve external domains.

Try setting your proxy like this:

```
client_args = {'proxies': {'https': 'http://proxy.company.com:10080'}}
```

Comment: using HTTPS gives SSLError.:(

Comment: you forgot to specify `http://` in your proxy url (yes, its `http` although your connection is `https`). Anyway, as https over a proxy is currently broken it isn't guaranteed that it will work. This depends on your proxy software. Even if it works it's not exactly the right thing, that is happening. If you want to know all the gory details you can search the requests bugtracker

Comment: Thanks a ton man!! It finally works.. I am unable to vote you up but I will definitely do that when I have reputation. Sorry. And yet again thanks. :)

Comment: When I try using Twython to retrieve tweets :
    `search = t.search(q='#tag',count=5)
    tweets = search['statuses']
    for tweet in tweets:
        print tweet['text']`

I have this problem:
 `File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twython\endpoints.py", line 130, in search
   return self.get('search/tweets', params=params)
   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twython\api.py", line 219, in get return self.request(endpoint, params=params, version=version)`

Followed by :
  `TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 400 (Bad Request), An error occurred processing your request.`

Comment: You should probably open a different question or file a bug on the twython bug tracker. I don't know anything about the twitter API or twython and the other guys are also more `requests` than `twython` people.

Answer (score 1):

In combination with @t-8ch's answer (which is that you must use a proxy as he has defined it), you should also realize that as of this moment, requests (the underlying library of Twython) does not support proxying over HTTPS. This is a problem with requests underlying library urllib3. It's a long running issue as far as I'm aware.

On top of that, reading a bit of Twython's [source](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/api.py#L102..L106) explains why `t.client_args` returns an empty dictionary. In short, if you were to instead print `t.client.proxies`, you'd see that indeed your proxies are being processed as they very well should be.

Finally, complaining about your workplace while on StackOverflow and linking to GitHub commits that have your GitHub username (and real name) associated with them in the comments is not the best idea. StackOverflow is indexed quite thoroughly by Google and there is little doubt that someone else might find this and associate it with you as easily as I have. On top of that, that commit has absolutely no effect on Twython's current behaviour. You're running down a rabbit hole with no end by chasing the author of that commit.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I am very sorry for having done that. Yes. I guess I shouldn't complain so much but something just made me very frustrated when I did. Have edited it accordingly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a domain name lookup failed. Assuming your configured DNS server can resolve Twitter's domain name (and surely it can), I would presume your DNS lookup for `proxy.company.com` failed. Try using a proxy by IP address instead of by hostname.

Comment: isn't this just because using HTTPS over proxies fails for us right now?

Comment: The proxy doesn't seem to be HTTPS.

Comment: using HTTPS gives SSLError. Tried doing `t.client_args = {'proxies': {'https': 'proxy.company.com:10080','http': 'proxy.company.com:10080'}}` as well as `t.client_args = {'proxies': {'https': 'proxy.company.com:10080'` however I get :
`
Traceback (most recent call last):` Skipping intermediate points to give final lines :
    `r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-1.2.3-py2.7.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 331, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol`